# Merging two Arrays using LinQ

Tags: c#, arrays, linq

I have two `arrays`:

```
var students  = new [] {"Elisa" ,"Sarah", "Frank","Frederic"};

var votes  = new[] {90, 70, 40,80};
```

How  can I  print something  like this using `linq`  if possible?

```
"Elisa 90"
"Sarah 70" 
"Frank 40"
"Frederic 80"
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You  can use  [Linq.Zip](http://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev12.query?appId=Dev12IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k(System.Linq.Enumerable.Zip%60%603);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework,Version%3Dv4.5);k(DevLang-csharp)&rd=true)

```
var students = new[] { "Elisa", "Sarah", "Frank", "Frederic" };
var votes = new[] { 90, 70, 40, 80 };
var studendsAndVotes = students.Zip(votes, (student, vote) => student + " " + vote);
```

from  MSDN
*`Applies a specified function to the corresponding elements of two sequences, producing a sequence of the results.`*